# How do we $\lim\limits{n\to\infty} \left(f(n)\cdot g(n)\right)$ where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(n)=\infty$?

Tags: limits

Is there some good formula(s) which can be used to find out the RHS of the below formula of lim?

$$\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left( \text{term which converges to zero}  \right) \cdot \left( \text{term which diverges to infinity}  \right)$$

Concretely, I want to prove the below equation of lim

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\pi}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) =1 $$

Of course, the left factor $\frac{n}{\pi}$ diverges and the right factor $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ converges to zero.

I know l'hopital theorem .

Transforming the formula as follows.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\pi}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) \\ = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\pi}\cdot\frac{ \sin\left(\pi/n\right)}{\cos\left(\pi/n\right)}$$

WIP

Comment: For the first question, there is no general formula: consider $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot n^2 = \infty$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot n = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a}{n} \cdot n = a$ for any $a \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @bostondynamicslover Next time you post a question, please avoid math-only titles. For more information, see [Guidelines for good use of MathJax on question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: @soupless I've read the post which you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim1**

$$ \lim_{ n  \to \infty} \frac{  n   }{ \pi   } \tan^{}\left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right) =1 $$

**Proof**

$$ \lim_{ n  \to \infty} \frac{  n   }{ \pi   } \tan^{}\left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right)  $$

$$ = \lim_{  n \to \infty}  \frac{  \frac{  n  }{  \pi  } \tan^{}\left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right)   }{  \frac{ 1   }{  1  }   }  $$

$$ = \lim_{  n \to \infty}  \frac{  \frac{  n  }{  \pi  } \tan^{}\left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right) \cdot \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  }{  \frac{ 1   }{  1  } \cdot \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  }   $$

$$ = \lim_{  n \to \infty}  \frac{   \tan^{}\left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right)   }{   \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  } ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{Each of the nominator and the denominator converges to zero .}   $$

$$ = \lim_{  n \to \infty}  \frac{   \tan^{\left( 1 \right) }\left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right)   }{   \left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right)'  } $$

$$ = \lim_{  n \to \infty}  \frac{   \sec^{2}\left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }   \right) \cdot \left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right)'   }{   \left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right)'  } $$

$$ = \lim_{ n \to \infty} \sec^{2}\left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right)  $$

$$ = \lim_{ n \to \infty} \frac{  1  }{ \cos^{2}\left( \frac{  \pi  }{  n  }  \right)    }   $$

$$ = 1 ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{QED .}  $$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} \left( \text{term which covnerges to zero}  \right) \cdot \left( \text{term which diverges to infinity}  \right) =\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} \left( \text{term which covnerges to zero}  \right) \cdot \frac{1}{\left( \text{term which diverges to zero}  \right)} =\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty}\frac{\left( \text{term which covnerges to zero}  \right)} {\left( \text{term which diverges to zero}  \right)}\Rightarrow$

l'hopital theorem